# React Router v4 and React Transition Group v2

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-transition-group

I am trying to find a working example of low level animations using the React Router v4 with React Transition Group v2. I have looked at the example on the React Router docs but they only use CSS Animation with one route.

This is how I currently use the React Router:

```
export const App = () => (
  <div className="app-container">
    <main className="app-container__content">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/projects/:slug" component={ProjectPage} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={StartPage} />
      </Switch>
    </main>
  </div>
);
```

And this is my Root.jsx:

```
const Root = ({ store, history }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />
      </Switch>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
);
```

I have tested the solution here: https://hackernoon.com/animated-page-transitions-with-react-router-4-reacttransitiongroup-and-animated-1ca17bd97a1a - but it doesn't work. Could some one point me in the right direction?

**Update**

I have tried like this, but the callback doesn't get called. So I end up with to pages in the dom.

```
export const App = ({ location }) => {
  console.log(location);

  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <main className="app-container__content">
        <ScrollToTop />
        <TransitionGroup>
          <Switch key={location.pathname} location={location}>
            <Route exact path="/projects/:slug" component={ProjectPage} />
            <Route exact path="/" component={StartPage} />
          </Switch>
        </TransitionGroup>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: If the hackernoon demo isn't working for you - I suggest you post the code that you're using just in case there's some small difference that has crept in from the tutorial code

Comment: @icc97 he isn't using the latest version of the React Transition Group. https://medium.com/@martinhaagensli/correct-the-v2-api-wasnt-officially-released-when-this-article-was-written-8b915d518fd2

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the `Transition` component itself

it should look something like this:

```
<TransitionGroup>
  <CSSTransition
    key={location.key}
    classNames="page-animation"
    timeout={{ enter: PAGE_ENTER_ANIMATION_SPEED, exit: PAGE_EXIT_ANIMATION_SPEED }}>
    <Switch location={location}>
      <Route exact path="/projects/:slug" component={ProjectPage} />
      <Route exact path="/" component={StartPage} />
    </Switch>
  </CSSTransition>
</TransitionGroup>
```

notice that the key is on the `CSSTransition` itself and not on the `Switch`

---

### Update

If you want to implement it by yourself
here is a basic implementation of `CSSTransition`

```
class MyTransition extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            inTransition: true,
            playAnimation: false,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({playAnimation: true});
        }, 1);

        this.removeClassesAndFireOnExited();
    }

    removeClassesAndFireOnExited() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({playAnimation: false, inTransition: false}, () => {
                if (!this.props.in) {
                    this.props.onExited(this);
                }
            });
        }, this.props.timeout[this.props.in ? 'enter' : 'exit']);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.in !== this.props.in) {
            this.setState({inTransition: true});
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({playAnimation: true});
            }, 1);

            this.removeClassesAndFireOnExited();
        }
    }

    render() {
        const baseClassName = this.props.in ? 'page-animation-enter' : 'page-animation-exit';
        const {inTransition, playAnimation} = this.state;

        const transitionClasses = [...(inTransition ? [baseClassName] : []), ...(playAnimation ? [baseClassName + '-active'] : [])];

        return (
            <div className={transitionClasses.join(' ')}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

you get `this.props.in` from `TransitionGroup` to indicate whether you are entering or leaving.
`this.props.onExited` is another prop that you get from `TransitionGroup`, you must call it when the exit animation completes, so `TransitionGroup` will know that you should be unmounted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am asking for a solution where you can use low level animations not CSSTransitions. CSSTransitions they have a lot of examples on their website, but it is harder to find a working example for low level animations.

Comment: in this case you can use Transition it self (CSSTransition is a HOC over Transition)
you can see it in react-transition-group implementation of [CSSTransition](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/master/src/CSSTransition.js#L255)

you just need to implement your own onEnter, onExit etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article explaining how to setup react-router v4 and react-transition-group with multiple routes and with transitions depending of the next state: https://medium.com/lalilo/dynamic-transitions-with-react-router-and-react-transition-group-69ab795815c9